# no postback on specific page

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net Routes in the Global.asax:
`routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "home", "~/index.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Profiles", "profile/{nick}/{profid}", "~/Profile.aspx");`

I have in my master page a top menu, in which there is a LinkButton with OnClick event.
Problem is, the postback works only on routed pages like "HOME" but not in the Profile (which is constructed out of /asdf/12345 instead of just /1235.

When clicking the top menu LinkButton in the profile page I get 404 page.
it doesnt even post to the page!

what can be wrong?

thanks

Comment: what happen if you go to /profile/asdf/1235? do you get 404?

Comment: yes... if i add to home something /home/asdfa/1234 instead of /home/ i get 404 as well

Comment: That's your problem, please post complete code so we help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I had to put in my Masterpage:
`this.form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;`

this fixed the form's action!